# Using return in while loop doesn't print properly in main function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am having trouble getting my **def simspin** to print properly in the main. When I run the function in the shell with manual data inputs it returns the proper data, but when it prints through the main function it doesn't print complete data. Is there something I can do different for **return** in **def** **simspin**?

```
from random import randrange
from random import random

def printintro(): **Removed for Purposes of this post**


def inputvalues():
    bankroll=int(input("Enter the number of dollars you start with:"))
    spins=int(input("Enter the number of spins you will play:"))
    bet=int(input("Enter how many dollars you will bet for each spin:"))
    print()
    return bankroll, spins, bet

def betstyle():.....**Removed for purposes of this post.**


def simspin(spins,placebet,bankroll,strategy,bet):
    wins=0
    losses=0
    spincount=0
    endingbank=bankroll
    netwinnings=0
    while spincount != spins and endingbank >0:
        spincount=spincount+1
        winningnumber=7
        if strategy == 's' and placebet == winningnumber:
            wins=wins+1
            endingbank=endingbank+(bet*35)
            netwinnings=netwinnings+bet*35

        elif strategy == 'e' and placebet== winningnumber:
            wins=wins+1
            endingbank=endingbank+bet+bet
            netwinnings=netwinnings+bet+bet

        elif strategy == 'd' and placebet== winningnumber:
            wins=wins+1
            endingbank=endingbank+bet+(bet*2)
            netwinnings=netwinnings+bet+(bet*2)

        else:
            losses=losses+1
            endingbank=endingbank-bet

    return wins,losses,spincount,endingbank,netwinnings


def printResults(spincount, wins, losses, endingbank, netwinnings):
    winsperc=wins/spincount
    lossperc=losses/spincount
    print()
    print("After {0} spins".format(spincount))
    print("Wins: {0} ({1}%)".format(wins,100*winsperc))
    print("Losses: {0} ({1}%)".format(losses,100*lossperc))
    print("Ending bank: ${0}".format(endingbank))
    print("Net winnings: ${0}".format(netwinnings))

def main():
    bankroll, spins, bet=inputvalues()
    printintro()
    strategy=placebet=betstyle()
    wins, losses, spincount, endingbank, netwinnings=simspin(spins,placebet,bankroll,strategy,bet)
    printResults(spincount,wins,losses,endingbank,netwinnings)
main()
```

The program currently prints the following...

```
Enter the number of dollars you start with:1000
Enter the number of spins you will play:1000
Enter how many dollars you will bet for each spin:1

Choose one of the following stragey choices
   -Bet on a (s)ingle number (pays 35 to 1)
   -Bet on a (e)ven or odd numbers (pays 1 to 1
   -Bet on a (d)ozen numbers (pays 2 to 1

Enter your strategy choice (s,e,d):s
Enter the single number you want to bet on (00 or 0 to 36): 7

**After 1000 spins
Wins: 0 (0.0%)
Losses: 1000 (100.0%)
Ending bank: $0
Net winnings: $0**
```

I want it to print...

```
Enter the number of dollars you start with:1000
Enter the number of spins you will play:1000
Enter how many dollars you will bet for each spin:1

Choose one of the following stragey choices
   -Bet on a (s)ingle number (pays 35 to 1)
   -Bet on a (e)ven or odd numbers (pays 1 to 1
   -Bet on a (d)ozen numbers (pays 2 to 1

Enter your strategy choice (s,e,d):s
Enter the single number you want to bet on (00 or 0 to 36): 7

**After 1000 spins
Wins: 1000 (1000.0%)
Losses: 0 (0.0%)
Ending bank: $36000
Net winnings: $35000**
```

Comment: Please show an example set of input, incorrect output, and expected/correct output.

Comment: can you debug by adding a print(strategy) please inside simspin function?

Comment: It prints the following....('s', '7')

Comment: Found out the issue in the main function. Thank you!